# sort integers positive then negative

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary of `'name': Obj` entries, where each `Obj` has a `num` parameter that takes a signed integer.  I want to convert this into an `OrderedDict` where the entries are sorted by positive `Obj.num` values, then negative numbers.

Sorting overall is no problem:

```
>>> data = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda tt: tt[1].num))
>>> print([val.num for key, val in data.items()])
[-5, -2, -1, 1, 2, 10, 100]
```

But I want to end up with either:
`[1, 2, 10, 100, -5, -2, -1]`
or
`[1, 2, 10, 100, -1, -2, -5]`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

reverse the sort, use `x >= 0` to get the positive numbers first, `-` the  numbers to put the negative numbers at the at the end and keep the order of positive from lowest to highest.

```
l = [-5, -2, -1, 1, 2, 10, 100]

print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x >= 0, -x), reverse=True))
```

For your dict:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda tt: (tt[1].num >= 0, -tt[1].num , reverse=True)))
```

Comment: Yep, I forgot to `-x`, should give you `[1, 2, 10, 100, -5, -2, -1]`

Comment: Awesome - Thanks!  What happens when `key` is a tuple?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix, the edit should do it, the same logic just accessing the tuple element.

Comment: Why not just `sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x < 0, x))`?